# File Server Partitioning

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.10, file-server

I am looking at turning a PC with a 1TB hard drive into a file server.  What is the "best practice"/recommended filesystem for such a server?

I was initially thinking of creating a seperate partition for just the files I'm serving, but not sure if that makes sense.  I'm trying to figure out if that would even provide lift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which OS are you using?

If it's Windows, just place all your documents in a sub-directory because it's nearly impossible to determine the long-term space requirements due to updates that seem to increase in size over time.

If it's Unix/Linux, then start with whatever the flavour/distribution recommends in the documentation as a starting point, increase as you feel is necessary (I like to have lots of extra slack available just in case I need it, so I tend to double or triple this minimum requirement), then just assign the rest to /usr/ and fill it up as needed.